# Running multiple android emulators and debugging a signalr app with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, signalr, visual-studio-2019

I have this simple [xamarin.forms signalr chat app](https://github.com/AlphaTechstudios/Xamarin-Forms/tree/master/ChatApp.Mobile) based on this [video](https://youtu.be/4tdHOZW1GHI)

It works fine on an android emulator and I can debug it ok. I want to have it interact with another emulator so I can see the interaction on the hub between the 2 clients.

My problem is, I cant get the 2 emulators to share the same instance of the running app/hub.

I've tried debugging emulator1 while deploying the app to emulator2 but spinning both up shows 2 separate instances that don't interact with each other.

The hub url is "http://10.0.2.2:2777/chathub" but I'm unsure if that should be different for the deployed app.

How do i get this to work and are the best practices for working with multiple emulators in xamarin.forms in visual studio 2019?

Comment: run the server on your host PC (IIS, self host cmd program)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I won't be able to debug it if it's hosted on IIS. Thanks tho